# Finding links in a bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I extracted the links I want with this:

```
link_soup = soup.find_all('ul', 'pagination')
```

but now I can't use `link_soup[0].find_all('a')['href']` if I use `link_soup[0].find('a')['href']`

it only shows the first link which isn't what I want. How would I go about getting all links returned in a list?

Snippet Below:

```html
<ul class="pagination">
<li><a href="link">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
<li><a href="link">&lt;</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">1</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs active"><a href="link">2</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">3</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">4</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">5</a></li>
<li><a href="link"> &gt;</a></li>
<li><a href="link"> &gt;&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to find `parent` tag using `find` and then all `child` using `find_all`.Hope this helps

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""<html><ul class="pagination">
<li><a href="link">&lt;&lt;</a></li>
<li><a href="link">&lt;</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">1</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs active"><a href="link">2</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">3</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">4</a></li>
<li class="hidden-xs"><a href="link">5</a></li>
<li><a href="link"> &gt;</a></li>
<li><a href="link"> &gt;&gt;</a></li>
</ul></html>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
ul=soup.find('ul')
for a in ul.find_all('a'):
  print(a['href'])
```

Output :

```
link
link
link
link
link
link
link
link
link
```